# OpenCL - Initializing program-scope variables from the host?

Tags: opencl

I have some general parameters declared as a global (__constant) struct, like so:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
    /// blah blah

} SomeParams;

__constant SomeParams Parameters;
```

in the kernel, I need to use it like so:

```
__kernel void Foo()
{
    int a = Parameters.a;
    /// do something useful...
}
```

I'm not sure how I can initialize the value of Parameters from the host before I execute the kernel.

I have no problem creating buffers, etc for kernel arguments, but since this isn't a kernel argument, what do I need to do?

I'm using the Cloo C#/OpenCL bindings, but even a raw CL API would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know (but I wouldn't swear by this), you can't initialize variables from the host code that are declared in that way (with one exception, see below).  You could declare a variable and initialize it like this:

```
__constant float pi = 3.14f;
```

You could also do something like this:

Kernel: `__constant float width = WIDTH`

Host: Build the kernel with a `-D` build parameter defining the value of `WIDTH`.

What I have done in the past is have the constant variable as a kernel parameter.

```
__kernel void Foo(__constant SomeParams Parameters)
{
    int a = Parameters.a;
    /// do something useful...
}
```

Then you can allocate and set the value just like any other kernel argument.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping not to have to pass the parameter collection around (it's used by at least six different kernels), but this is a workable solution. Am I correct in that `__constant` doesn't come out of the limited memory available to each core?

Comment: One wonders, then why the compiler wouldn't throw a warning about uninitialized global variables.

Comment: You can use the `clGetDeviceInfo(...)` method with `CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE` to get the number of bytes available on the device for the constant buffer (those variables marked __constant).  Pass `CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE` to get the size of local memory for the devices (those variables marked __local).  One more caveat... there is a limit to the number of __constant parameters you can pass to a kernel.  To get that number, pass `CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_ARGS`.  The OpenCL spec states that the minimum value for this is 8 (but could be more depending on the device).

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I might not have been clearly answering your question.  No, variables marked `__constant` come out of a different pool of memory than variables marked `__local`, `__private`, or `__global`.

Comment: I found this statement in the AMD "Introduction to OpenCL Programming" Guid: `Constant memory is a region of global memory that stays constant throughout the execution of the kernel. Work-items have only read access to this region. The host is permitted both read and write access.' Now if only they'd say HOW the host is permitted to write...